# Reflection of a specific point over the nine point center

Tags: geometry

Consider a $\Delta ABC$ with angle bisector $AI$, and $N$ be its nine point center. I was wondering if a point, say $P$ (which forms the circumcenter of $\Delta KOH$ where $AK\perp BC$ and $H$ is orthocenter of $\Delta ABC$), if reflected over $N$ such that the reflected point $Q$ lies on angle bisector of $\angle BAC$, would it necessarily mean that $N$ belongs to $AI$ as well?

I know that $H$ and $O$ are isogonal to each other.

But can't proceed anything further. Geogebra experimentation tells me that it is true. But please help me prove it.

And please, no coordinate or complex or any other bash.

Comment: I would have thought that if $Q$ lies on $AI$ and on the extension of $PN$ then $N$ lies on $AI$ if and only if $P$ lies on $AI$ in which case the lines $AI$ and $PN$ coincide

Comment: @Henry I've edited the question to some extent. In this case, how would you show that $P$ belongs to $AI$? (where $I$ is the incentre of $\Delta ABC$)